# jQuery/HTML/PHP - Why does my form submit not work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am using jQuery to generate a form when a modal dialog pops up, the form exists and looks good and I am not receiving any errors in my console...

The problem is when I press the submit button, it doens't do anything.. I checked the network tab in Chrome and it did'nt sent any requests...

This is the particular jQuery code:

```
 function getLogin() {
    var html = '<div class="box" id="login">';
        html+='<div id="modalheader"><img id="kruis" src="img/kruis.png"/></div>';
        html+='<div id="modalcontent"><forrm action="includes/login.php" method="post"><table>';
        html+='<tr>';
            html+='<td>Gebruiker</td>';
            html+='<td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" size="8" required></td>';
        html+='</tr>';
        html+='<tr>';
            html+='<td rowspan="2">Wachtwoord</td>';
            html+='<td><input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" size="8" required></td>';
        html+='</tr>';
        html+='<tr>';
            html+='<td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>';
        html+='</tr>';
        html+= '</table></form></div>';
        html+='<div id="modalfooter">97039259</div>';
        container.append(html);
}
```

Comment: Where is your form opening tag? Do you have action and method set on it?

Comment: replace forrm with form

Comment: Typo: `<forrm action...`

Comment: Thanks everyone...

Comment: By the way, the submit button should not be in the table, semantically speaking. It is not part of the data structure.

Comment: Maybe off-topic but if it helps to clear your code, you can use [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Answer (score 2):

Please check your script. you can mistake in **`<form></form>`** tag

You have open form tag with **`<forrm action="includes/login.php" method="post">`** .

Answer (score 0):

change `<forrm action="includes/login.php" method="post">` to

`<form action="includes/login.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in `form` tag it. It should be `form` not `forrm`

```
function getLogin() {
var html = '<div class="box" id="login">';
    html+='<div id="modalheader"><img id="kruis" src="img/kruis.png"/></div>';
    html+='<div id="modalcontent"><form action="includes/login.php" method="post"><table>';
    html+='<tr>';
        html+='<td>Gebruiker</td>';
        html+='<td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" size="8" required></td>';
    html+='</tr>';
    html+='<tr>';
        html+='<td rowspan="2">Wachtwoord</td>';
        html+='<td><input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" size="8" required></td>';
    html+='</tr>';
    html+='<tr>';
        html+='<td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>';
    html+='</tr>';
    html+= '</table></form></div>';
    html+='<div id="modalfooter">97039259</div>';
    container.append(html);
}
```